# While Loop and Touch Events Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, while-loop

I'm trying to create an iOS triggering app that sends a signal if triggered when the app is armed. I've generated the signal to be sent when triggered and a button that changes the app from armed to unarmed.

When I touch the button making the app armed, it then goes into a while loop that runs listening to see if the app has been triggered and sends the signal if triggered. However by doing this I am unable to touch the button that now says to unarm the app. This is what I have so far:

```
    var trigger = AVAudioPlayer()
func playMySound(){
    let triggerSoundURL =  NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("trigger", withExtension: "wav")!
    trigger = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: triggerSoundURL)
    trigger.prepareToPlay()
    trigger.play()
}

var armed = 0
@IBAction func arm() {
    if(armed==0){
        armed=1
        armButton.setTitle("Armed", forState: .Normal)
        triggering();
    }
    else{
        armed=0
        armButton.setTitle("Arm", forState: .Normal)
    }
}

func triggering() -> Void {
    while(armed==1){
        playMySound()
        arm()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are blocking main thread, thats why you can`t touch the button.
Try to change your "triggering" function to something like this:

```
func triggering() -> Void {
    dipsatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)){
        while(armed==1){
            playMySound()
            arm()
        }
    }
}
```